# For this program I am trying to print out the value of the function but it's printing the location in the memory

Tags: python

```
def twoDim(foo):
        two_d= []
        new = []
        for i in range(0,9):
            for j in range(0,9):
                new.append(foo)
            two_d.append(new)
twoDim(0)
print(twoDim)
```

Comment: `print(twoDim)` prints _the function itself_. You already know how to _call_ the function, because you did it on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

twoDim is name for a function. You want to see result of its call

```
print(twoDim(0))
```

or

```
result = twoDim(0)
print(result)
```

Your function also doesn't return anything currently so any result of its call will be None. You need to add return statement with whatever variable you want to be the output of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't have a return statement which returns a value when the function is called so you can add a return statement which returns the value you expect the function to have when using it with the print function.

Also, keep in mind that using only the name of the function without parenthesis like you did in your code doesn't call the function but returns the memory location of your function object.

Answer (score 0):

twoDim is the function name.

So, instead of print(twoDim), you should write print(twoDim(0)) which means calling the function and printing its return value.

In your case, twoDim function doesn't have a return value, so the correct print statement would also not print anything.

If you intend to print two_d and new, you can do that in the function itself and then just call the function OR return something from the function.